# Verb after "which in turn"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

In this sentence:

As a result, the process of importation and exportation sets in, which in turn helps world economy greatly.

The verb in question is the word help. Where does it need to agree with? It is with the subject process? Or should it be in the past tense as in:

As a result, the process of importation and exportation sets in, which in turn helped world economy greatly.

Comment: The subject is *the process*, but any tense could be used and it would be grammatical. Only the context can determine if the process helped, helps, or will help word economy. The present tense is the most logical based on what's provided (*sets in* is the present tense), but it's not required.

Comment: @jason Thank you for clarifying.